# Effect of internal force on the weight of an object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, weight

A man is holding a closed cage on the palm of his hand with a bird in it. 
When the bird flies with an upward acceleration inside the cage, it feels heavier. 
But the force due to the bird in the cage is actually an internal force on the cage, and internal forces don't cause acceleration of the body, then how does the cage feel heavier?

Answer (score 1):

Let's change the question slightly.

If I have a closed box, and inside the box is a weight on a string, then when I hold the box I feel the weight of box plus the extra weight.

Now something cuts the string, and the weight starts to drop. The internal force of the string on the box stops, and the box will (temporarily) feel lighter, while the weight is dropping freely inside.

While the box is stationary, the center of mass of the box-plus-weight system is dropping.

The same reasoning can be applied to any compound system where one part is moving and the other part is not. The total *external* force must be sufficient to cause the acceleration of the center of mass of the *total system* (in this case, bird plus cage). So when the bird accelerates up, it produces a flow of air in the cage that increases the pressure on the bottom more than on the top - this creates a net downward force on the cage, and upward force on the bird. You are holding the box, and are producing an additional force on the box that keeps the box still. This keeps the box in equilibrium and allows the bird to fly up.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the cage to be the system.

For the bird to fly upwards it needs to move some air downwards.  That air hitting the floor of the cage imparts a force on the floor as the N3L reaction to the floor imparting a force on the air when the air hits the floor.?

Comment: but that is an internal force. How can it affect the weight of the cage?

Comment: What is an internal force?  The system is just the cage not the air within it.  You would get the same effect if you blasted air onto the base of the cage.

Comment: Why is it only the cage? Does that mean that the bird is not the part of the system too?

Comment: if the bird accelerates upwards it must have a force acting on it upwards.  This force is provided by the air inside the cage when the bird is flapping its wings.  The force on the air provided by the bird's wings accelerates the air down.  That air hits the base of the cage and the cage exerts a force on the air upwards.  So the air exerts a force on the base of the cage downwards.  If the cage is not to accelerate downwards there must be a force on the cage upwards due to the hand.  This is no different to the bird being on the floor with bent legs, then straightening them.

Answer (score 0):

If the bird is **accelerating** upward, the center of mass of the combined system of cage plus bird is accelerating upward.  However, if the bird is just hovering, the combined apparent weight should not change.

Comment: How does that shift of COM make the cage heavy?

Comment: It doesn't make the cage weight more.  But, it requires a greater upward force to hold the cage stationary.  In the case where the bird is hovering, the effect is not still there.  The acceleration of the center of mass in this case is zero.  The air in the cage just supports the weight of the bird, but then the reaction force on the air is transmitted to the cage.  This reaction force is just equal to the weight of the bird.  So, the total force to support the cage if the bird is hovering is just equal to the weight of the bird plus the weight of the cage.  This assms no air enters or lves.